# What's the best way to manage a multi-user project on github?

Tags: git, github

I'm looking to host a new project on github. This project will be worked on by two coders. One of these coders will also be the project manager who will have overall control over the github repo.

I've followed the instructions regarding forking a github project at http://help.github.com/forking/. This all works fine and I'm working on the basis that the main repo is controlled by the lead coder, with the secondary coder working on a fork and submitting pull requests to the lead.

A problem arises with this, however, when changes are made to the main branch and not pulled by the secondary coder into their fork. The secondary coder could then make changes to their own fork and submit a pull request to the lead, only for their patches to not match up with the main branch.

What's the best way to manage this? I've not committed too much time to git/github, so I'm totally up for checking out other hosted solutions if they're better. Simplicity is the key!

Answer (score 2):

The admin view of the lead developer's repository will allow him to add the other developer's github account as one of possibly many collaborators (depends on your github plan, public repositories can have unlimited public collaborators). That way, all of them should be able to work with the repository, at least regarding pushing of their commits (that's what I tried out so far). I suppose it includes the ability for collaborators to create branches and the like.

Answer (score 0):

The coder need made one branch by feature and pull all branches. You can merge it if you want.
The coder not change his master branch and this it always like lead master branch